# CSS priority with 2 importants

Tags: html, css

I have two CSS files imported. I can change the first imported CSS file, but can not  modify second one. I also cannot edit the HTML, only the CSS.

I have an element:

```html
<tr id="mad3161b5-co_0" role="presentation" control="true" class="  multiparttext leafspacer verticalSpacer" style="vertical-align:top;">
    <td id="mad3161b5-co2_0" role="presentation" nowrap="nowrap" class="  multiparttext leafspacer verticalSpacer" style="">
        <label id="mad3161b5-lb" ctype="label" noclick="1" targetid="mad3161b5-lb" class="text label  " style="display:block;margin-top: 5px;" for="mad3161b5-tb">some text</label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In the second, uneditable CSS file there is:

```css
.leafspacer td > label { padding-top: 7px !important; }
```

I need to add a rule to override padding-top to 5.
I tried this:

```css
.leafspacer tr > td > label { padding-top: 5px !important; }
```

or

```css
tr > td > label { padding-top: 5px !important; }
```

Based on how I understand priority rules, `padding-top: 5px !important;` should have more priority and override padding 7, but it doesn't work.

How I can override padding 7 with 5 based on restrictions that I cannot edit HTML and can edit only first imported CSS file?

Comment: `.leafspacer tr > td > label` is wrong as it means a child `tr` but the `tr` is the leafspacer.  try `tr.leafspacer td > label`.  Have a read of this as it explains [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Do they all have the same class? .leafspacer tr > td > label.label { padding-top: 5px !important; } may be more specific and override

Comment: that way it works: .leafspacer td > label.label {padding-top: 5px !important; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!important`s are bad. Period.

If you get to a problem like that, it indicates that your project needs refactoring, in a way that it doesn't have to use `!important`s.

---

To answer the question, the selector you're trying to override has specificity of `(0,1,2)!` (0 IDs, 1 class, 2 other, important).

To override that selector, you need at least `(0,1,3)!` or `(0,2,0)!`.

By looking at the attempts you made, you may see that

```
.leafspacer tr > td > label { padding-top: 5px !important; }
```

has a specificity of `(0,1,3)!`, so it should work. However, it also changes the behaviour of the selector (would require the `tr` to be *in* the `.leafspacer`, which is not the case), so it doesn't match.

The other attempt you made has an even lower specificity of `(0,0,3)!`, so it doesn't work.

---

To solve the problem, you can change your first attempt to match the element:

```
tr.leafspacer > td > label { padding-top: 5px !important; }
```

However, that still differs from the behaviour of the unchangeable CSS (requires the `tr`) that could break your code if the HTML structure changes.

So, your best workaround would be to repeat the class, giving the selector a `(0,2,2)!` specificity without changing behaviour:

```
.leafspacer.leafspacer td > label { padding-top: 5px !important; }
```

That will work in all cases, but I can't emphasise enough that you should **refactor the code to avoid using `!important`s if you have any way to do so!**

Answer (score -1):

.leafspacer td > label.label {padding-top: 5px !important; }

Comment: Please take a moment to read [answer] and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)